# Persistent empty sponsor section above excerpt in single-tag tabs

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

The area above the excerpt for sponsor info in single-tag tabs is now showing as an empty block, both in tags where the content has been dismissed, and tags that have no sponsor. This normally collapses after dismissing the sponsor content, and shouldn't show up at all on tags without sponsors.

Normal appearance for a sponsored tag:

> [image: normal screenshot]

Appearance after dismissing content, and reloading:

> [image: dismissed screenshot]

Tag without a sponsor:

> [image: no sponsor screenshot]

This is happening even on tags for which I'd dismissed the content long ago:

> [image: long-dismissed screenshot]

I wouldn't think this is browser-specific, but if others can't repro this, I'll add details of my environment.

Comment: On Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/tag-page-shows-lots-of-empty-space

Comment: Yeah, this is really annoying. There is already so much space lost, and now even more for more ads...

Comment: Seems to be fixed, now: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293382.